# Copy records(row by row) from S3 to SQS - Using AWS Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-batch

I have setup a Glue Job which runs concurrently to process input files and writes it down to S3. The Glue job runs periodically (not a one time job).

The output in S3 is in a form of csv file. The requirement is to copy all those records into Aws SQS. Assuming there might be 100s of files, each containing upto million records.

Initially i was planning to have a lambda event to send the records row by row. however, from the doc i see a time limit for lambda as 15 mins- [https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/#:~:text=You%20can%20now%20configure%20your,Lambda%20function%20was%205%20minutes](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20now%20configure%20your,Lambda%20function%20was%205%20minutes).

Will it be better to use AWS Batch for copying the records from S3 to SQS ? I believe, AWS Batch has the capability to scale the process when needed and also perform the task in parallel.

I want to know if AWS Batch is a right pick or am i trying to more complicate the design ?

Comment: Is it something that you do once only, or your glue job runs regularly and those csv files should be process automatically after each job?

Comment: the glue jobs run regularly and csv files should be processed automatically after each job

Comment: Bash Array job could process the file in parallel. So you can still have s3 to push events to sqs when your csv are generated from glue. The bash array job would start multiple containers to pull from the sqs queue and process the csv.

Comment: Bash Array Job - is this part of AWS batch service ?

Comment: Yes, Batch [array jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/array_jobs.html) to run highly parallel applications.